# How to get the rank of a specific user based on the summation of scores?

Tags: mysql

I write the following MySQL command to get the sum of the score for the students and rank them accordingly.

```
SELECT student_id, thescore, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rankstudent 
FROM
(
    SELECT student_id, SUM(score) AS thescore
    FROM school_ranking
    WHERE school like '%Standard6%' and student_id <> ''
    GROUP BY student_id
    ORDER BY thescore DESC

) Sub1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) Sub2
```

Following is the result:

```
student_id   thescore    rankstudent
J007766      5739            1 
J007625      5159            2 
J007629      5158            3 
J007713      4460            4 
J007690      4384            5
```

My question is how to get the rank for a specific student?
For example, how to get the rank of a student with an id of 'J007625'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rankstudent FROM (
SELECT student_id, thescore, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rankstudent 
FROM
(
    SELECT student_id, SUM(score) AS thescore
    FROM school_ranking
    WHERE school like '%Standard6%' and student_id <> ''
    GROUP BY student_id
    ORDER BY thescore DESC

) Sub1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) Sub2
) Sub3
WHERE `Sub3`.`student_id` = "J007625"
```

Comment: I execute the command, and obtain rankstudent = 1. J007625 is in the second place, and the answer should be rankstudent = 2.

Comment: Wistar, the code works perfectly well, and gives the correct ranking. Excellent job! Thank you so much for the input and assistance.